# Javascript code produces concatenation when addition expected?

Tags: javascript

```
    var var1;
    var var2;

    var1 = readCookie('cookie_name');

    var2 = +var1 + 1;

    alert(var1);
    alert(var2);
```

Above snippet of JS has me baffled. Unless I code the workaround oddity of '+var1', the result is '11' not 2 (assuming var1=1 and var2=1). So it seems I am getting some sort of concatenation instead of addition. My only thought is this must have something to do with the fact that var1 is a value imported from a cookie. Or it is a bug in JS. Or I am going mad. Take your pick.

Comment: I don't see how `var1` will be anything other than `NaN`, since the value of `var2` is never set to anything (its value is `undefined`).  Also, the third line is irrelevant since you subsequently overwrite the value - unless `readCookie` somehow has a side effect of manipulating `var2`, but you didn't give the implementation so I'm not sure what you expect.  Voting to close as incomplete.

Comment: @Matt: Maybe a typo and should be `var2 = readCookie(...)`...

Comment: Perhaps, but then I'd also want to see an example value that was returned by that function, otherwise it's still unreproducible.

Comment: If one of the operands is a string, `+` performs string concatenation. So `readCookie` seems to be returning a string. Are you wondering what `+var1` is doing exactly? Otherwise I don't understand your question...

Comment: Sorry, my typos. I have fixed them.

Comment: Please read the documentation on the plus operator, or any basic JS tutorial.

Comment: @FelixKling This is crux of the problem. readCookie is returning a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing `readCookie('cookie_name')` is returning a `String`. Try:

```
var1 = parseInt(readCookie('cookie_name'));
```

To get `var1` as `int` but you may want to try the following to clean things up.

```
var var1 = parseInt(readCookie('cookie_name'));
var var2 = var1 + 1;

alert(var1); // should be the value of the cookie or 0
alert(var2);
```

Edit: Changes made based on edited question. Makes more sense now too :]

Comment: I tried parseInt and it worked. At least it produced the same results as my unconventional +var1 method. I am not sure +var1 is sound code, so I will go with your solution. It seems that the value stored in the cookie was a string value. I have used cookie values many times in my code without problems, but perhaps I have not tried to perform arithmetic operations on cookie contents before.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to keep the original version of `var1` around, and as long as you are always adding one, consider the alternative of doing

```
var1++
```

This will coerce the value to a number, and add one to it.

Comment: This was a good idea. I tested it in my real code, but it did not work, at least not in my application. But it did coerce a number value.

Answer (score 0):

`+var2` does a number conversion.`(+)` operator before the variable does the trick.So `+var1+1` will be 2. Otherwise this

```
var1 = readCookie('cookie_name');
```

is probably a string of value `1` and on addition of string & number will result in `11`

Comment: For completeness, provide a reference to documentation for the unary plus operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that var1 contains a numeric expression then you can use:

```
var2 = Number(var1) + 1;
alert(var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check is a number or not. if number then change it in to Number,by passing it to number function.

```
var var1;
var var2;

var1 = readCookie('cookie_name');

var1 = var1.isNaN()?var1:Number(var1); 

var2 = var1 + 1; //instead of your Code (+var1 + 1)
alert(var1);
alert(var2);
```

Comment: Did you mean `isNaN(var1)` by any chance? What's the point of doing `Number(var1)` **and** `+var1` later?

Comment: For every case. Strings don't have a `isNaN()` method. Try the following in your browser console: `"foo".isNaN()`.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to parse var2 to integer and your problem will get solved.

try this.

var1 = **paresInt**(+var2) + 1;

Comment: You should read the question again. Also there is no point in passing a *number* to `parseInt`. `parseInt` is supposed to operate on *strings*.

Comment: I did not test this, but I tested the parseInt solution given above @Tigger and it appears to solve the problem. The question I now ask myself is whether all JS cookies are stored as strings by default. If so, even if they look like integers, cookie contents are not. This is handy to know.

Comment: @Poppy: Yes, cookies are just text / strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie